# query this return list to show only records for a particular person. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I will like to query this return list to show only records for a particular person. Right now its show all records in the table. I am using ASP.NET MVC.
This is my code

```
    public ActionResult Policies()
    {


        var eList = new List<PolicyDTO>();
        using (var ctx = new RetailPlusEntities())
        {
            eList = ctx.POLICies.Select(rec => new PolicyDTO()

            {
                ID = rec.ID,
                CUSTOMERID = rec.CUSTOMERID,
                POLICYNO = rec.POLICYNO,
                PLANID = rec.PLANID,
                COMMENCEMENTDATE = rec.COMMENCEMENTDATE,
                MATURITYDATE = rec.MATURITYDATE,
                INITIALCONTRIBUTION = rec.INITIALCONTRIBUTION,
                CARDNO = rec.CARDNO,
                MARKERTERID = rec.MARKERTERID,
                COLLECTORID = rec.COLLECTORID,
                COVERID = rec.COVERID,
                STATUS = rec.STATUS,
                BRANCHID = rec.BRANCHID,
                BranchName = rec.BRANCH.NAME,
                EmployeName = rec.EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME,
                StatusName = rec.STATUS1.NAME,

           }).ToList();

         //   }).Where(a => a.COLLECTORID.Equals(empID)).ToList();

        }

        return View(eList);

    }
```

Comment: Why you're not using `Where` (it's commented out)?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public ActionResult Policies()
{
    using (var ctx = new RetailPlusEntities())
    {
        var eList = ctx.POLICies
            .Where(a => a.COLLECTORID == empID)
            .Select(rec => new PolicyDTO()

        {
            ID = rec.ID,
            CUSTOMERID = rec.CUSTOMERID,
            POLICYNO = rec.POLICYNO,
            PLANID = rec.PLANID,
            COMMENCEMENTDATE = rec.COMMENCEMENTDATE,
            MATURITYDATE = rec.MATURITYDATE,
            INITIALCONTRIBUTION = rec.INITIALCONTRIBUTION,
            CARDNO = rec.CARDNO,
            MARKERTERID = rec.MARKERTERID,
            COLLECTORID = rec.COLLECTORID,
            COVERID = rec.COVERID,
            STATUS = rec.STATUS,
            BRANCHID = rec.BRANCHID,
            BranchName = rec.BRANCH.NAME,
            EmployeName = rec.EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME,
            StatusName = rec.STATUS1.NAME,

        }).ToList();
        return View(eList);
    }
}
```

I removed the redundant initialization of `eList` that you immediately throw away, and return the result to the client. You just have to decide where you get `empID` from.

Answer (score 0):

```
public  ActionResult  Policies()
    {
        using (var ctx = new RetailPlusEntities())
        {
            var eList = ctx.POLICies
                .Where(a => a.COLLECTORID == empID).FirstOrDefult()
                .Select(rec => new PolicyDTO()

            {
                ID = rec.ID,
                CUSTOMERID = rec.CUSTOMERID,
                POLICYNO = rec.POLICYNO,
                PLANID = rec.PLANID,
                COMMENCEMENTDATE = rec.COMMENCEMENTDATE,
                MATURITYDATE = rec.MATURITYDATE,
                INITIALCONTRIBUTION = rec.INITIALCONTRIBUTION,
                CARDNO = rec.CARDNO,
                MARKERTERID = rec.MARKERTERID,
                COLLECTORID = rec.COLLECTORID,
                COVERID = rec.COVERID,
                STATUS = rec.STATUS,
                BRANCHID = rec.BRANCHID,
                BranchName = rec.BRANCH.NAME,
                EmployeName = rec.EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME,
                StatusName = rec.STATUS1.NAME,

            }).ToList();
            return View(eList);
        }
    }
```